# Using regex need to add string at begining of the result

Tags: java, regex, apache-pig

I need to add string using regex at beginning of result. My working regex is:

```
<img id="main-image" src="(.*?)"
```

and their result is:

```
/images/product/400x400/662/662544_400x400.jpg
```

I am trying to add *www.xyz.com* at beginning of the result using regex 
so that actual result would be like this.

```
www.xyz.com/images/product/400x400/662/662544_400x400.jpg
```

For parsing the regex I am using Java UDF and pig

Is there any way to do this, please advise.

Comment: What language? Javascript?

Comment: For regex parsing I am using java

Comment: can't you just do `"www.xyz.com" + result`?

Comment: I am extracting image data from website. here **result** is not fixed it can be changed for next image but **www.xyz.com** is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to incorporate the substitution into the regex if you're using Pig.  You don't need to write your own UDF, either, if that's what you're doing.  Use the built-in functions `REGEX_EXTRACT` and `CONCAT`:

```
DESCRIBE A;
A: {tag: chararray}

DUMP A;
(<img id="main-image" src="/images/product/400x400/662/662544_400x400.jpg">)

B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT('www.xyz.com', REGEX_EXTRACT(tag, '<img id="main-image" src="(.*?)"', 1));

DUMP B;
(www.xyz.com/images/product/400x400/662/662544_400x400.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language. In Perl you need a substitution. I see PCRE lazy quantifiers in your code, so it *could* be Perl:

```
s/<img id="main-image" src="(.*?)"/www.xyz.com$1/;
```

Comment: That is not correct! That substitution would replace the whole img-tag with just the modified url. This should work better: `s/<img id="main-image" src="(.*?)"/<img id="main-image" src="www.xyz.com$1"/;`

Comment: Based on the question, replacing the whole `img` tag seems to be what the OP wants.